# Using sbt to generate a managed resource flattens the directory

Tags: scala, sbt

Since we use drools and this is coupled to maven I want to generate a pom.properties like maven does.
I need to create a file like `module-x/target/scala-2.11/resource_managed/META-INF/maven/com.foo/module-x/pom.properties`

The following code generates this file just fine. But the problem is, that sbt then places the file in `module-x/target/scala-2.11/classes/pom.properties` (completely drops the path)

```
resourceGenerators in Compile += Def.task {
      val file = resourceManaged.value / s"META-INF/maven/com.foo/${name.value}/pom.properties"
      val contents = s"""
version=$usedProjectV
groupId=com.foo
artifactId=${name.value}"""
      IO.write(file, contents)
      streams.value.log.info(s"generated $file")
      Seq(file)
    }.taskValue
```

How can I instruct sbt to retain the path?

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

sbt is flattening because it expects generated resources to be in `Compile / resourceManaged` rather than `resourceManaged`.

Change your second line to the following and sbt will retain the resources paths:

```
val file = (Compile / resourceManaged).value / s"META-INF/maven/com.foo/${name.value}/pom.properties"
```

### Background

`resourceManaged` has different values along the configuration axis:

```
sbt> show resourceManaged
[info] ./target/scala-2.13/resource_managed
sbt> show Compile / resourceManaged
[info] ./target/scala-2.13/resource_managed/main
sbt> show Test / resourceManaged
[info] ./target/scala-2.13/resource_managed/test
```

Specifically, the [copyResources](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/53299b79bd8187956e65ecb9eb97065975225ec6/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Defaults.scala#L2141-L2142) task is what's doing the flattening.